# How to keep rows where value is in any of multiple columns

Tags: r

I want to keep rows where any column where the column name contains 'NonAcid' is >50

My dataset:

```
    structure(list(RSAPNonAcidStomach = c(NA, 50, 0, 0), RSAPNonAcidThroat = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 0), RSAPNonAcidDysphagia = c(100, 0, 0, 0), RSAPAcidThroat = c(NA, 
NA, 75, NA)), .Names = c("RSAPNonAcidStomach", "RSAPNonAcidThroat", 
"RSAPNonAcidDysphagia", "RSAPAcidThroat"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

output:

```
RSAPNonAcidStomach RSAPNonAcidThroat RSAPNonAcidDysphagia RSAPAcidThroat
    NA                 NA             100                  NA
    50                 NA               0                  NA
```

I have tried:

```
dfwNon<-df[which(apply,df[grepl(".*RSAPNonAcid.*",names(df))],1,max)>50,]
```

but it tells me I have an unused argument max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Vectorized way. The part of `df[grepl('NonAcid', names(df))] >= 50` creates a logical matrix with the columns of interest for the values that are >= 50. We then use `rowSums` and if it is greater than 0 then it means that the specific row has at least 1 value 50 or greater. We use that to index the data frame.

```
df[rowSums(df[grepl('NonAcid', names(df))] >= 50, na.rm = TRUE) >0, ]

#  RSAPNonAcidStomach RSAPNonAcidThroat RSAPNonAcidDysphagia RSAPAcidThroat
#1                 NA                NA                  100             NA
#2                 50                NA                    0             NA
```

Comment: Hi although the example doesnt show it, rowsums doesnt always work as sometimes the columns have 25,25,25,25 so I cant really use that although its a useful method so point given

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Columns have 25 what?

Comment: doesnt your method sum all the columns in a row and if >50 then the row is kept? But if the row contains 25,25,25,25 then the row will be kept although none are greater than 50. Have it misunderstood?

Comment: Yes you have :). Let me explain

Comment: I see. Very clever. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sticking closer to your original method, this should fix your code:

```
dfwNon<-df[apply(df[,which(grepl("RSAPNonAcid",names(df)))],1,max, na.rm=TRUE)>50,]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grepl` to get the column indices of the data with "NonAcid" and then `apply` our search criteria (any value >= 50) rowwise with `margin=1`. As we used `na.rm=TRUE` this returns a Logical TRUE/FALSE vector which can be used to index the data.

```
dat[apply(dat[,grepl("NonAcid",names(dat),fixed=TRUE)],1,function(x) any(x>=50,na.rm=TRUE)),]
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer so that others can learn from it? Thanks!